# How to find all linear subsequence with R

Tags: r, algorithm, subsequence

I'm looking for a R function or code which may give me a list of all linear subsequences of length k from a sequence of length n where the k-linear subsequences are defined as sequences of the form X(ai+b) with a>0 and b>=0. Let's assume that this sequence is given (position i of numbers within sequence is given in brackets):

5(1) 3(2) 8(3) 9(4) 2(5)

Thus, n = 5 and I'm interested in all 3-linear subsequences (k = 3). Thus I'd like to obtain as a result of my R function the result

5(1) 3(2) 8(3)

3(2) 8(3) 9(4)

8(3) 9(4) 2(5)

5(1) 8(3) 2(5)

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start with. Thus, any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Assume:

```
n <- 5
k <- 3
```

**1)** Then try this:

```
filter_linear <- function(x) if (sd(diff(x)) == 0) x else NA
na.omit(t(combn(n, k, filter_linear)))
```

giving (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 5) and so on as rows of the output matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    5
[3,]    2    3    4
[4,]    3    4    5
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 2 3 4 6 8 9
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

**2)** A variation would be:

```
is_linear <- function(x) sd(diff(x)) == 0
Filter(is_linear, as.data.frame(combn(n, k)))
```

giving the results in the columns of the output data.frame:

```
  V1 V5 V7 V10
1  1  1  2   3
2  2  3  3   4
3  3  5  4   5
```

Comment: You're da bomb. Thanks a lot!